# MPI barrier not blocking

Tags: fortran, mpi

Up until now I believed that MPI barrier was blocking. So when a process encounters an MPI barrier it should stop and wait for the others to arrive at the same barrier.

Then at some point I programmed the following bug:

```
[...]
if (my_rank==0) then
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
end if 
[...]
```

Now I would have expected that all other processes continue their work and will eventually hang at the next blocking mpi call. While process 0 waits indefinitely at the above barrier.

However this is not what happened. All processes continued to execute and they were all hanging at the next mpi call in the code. I printed out the rank of all the processes right before this second mpi call, so I know they all arrived at that point, including task 0.

I troubleshooted like crazy to find the error, until I finally looked back further and further in the code and found the above bug.

Has anyone ever encountered behavior like this? Do I have a misconception of mpi_barrier works? I am using mvapich2.2 and ifort15.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This is an invalid MPI program and therefore you are observing an undefined behaviour. MPI requires that the collective calls in all ranks follow the same sequence. In your case, one rank makes an out-of-sequence call to `MPI_BARRIER`. Since it is unspecified how exactly the barrier is implemented, and since collective operations in generic MPI libraries are usually implemented internally using point-to-point communication, an out-of-sequence collective could interfere with other MPI calls and result in the observed behaviour.

Comment: If you need a barrier for one (or some) rank(s) in one place and the same one for others in another place with other MPI communication in between, you could use a non-blocking barrier (MPI_Ibarrier).

Comment: @haraldkl, this is only true if "other MPI communication in between" does not include collective communication over the same communicator - the sequence of all collectives over a particular communicator, blocking or not, must be same in all ranks.